# Multiple payload for a single request in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember data framework for api requests. Is there any way to have two payloads for a single api request?

Comment: Two payloads of different types, as in user and permissions or two payloads both users ?

Comment: What you're looking for is [RSVP.hash](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_hash)

Answer (score 0):

With json-api you can include related types, for examples see [here](http://jsonapi.org/examples/)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
      "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
      "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {"id": "42", "type": "people"}
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "people",
      "id": "42",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 80,
        "gender": "male"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In this example you see the `article` has a relationship called `author` of type `people`, which is then `included` in the same payload.

Comment: My need is to have two different payloads parallely. For example.
{payload1: {name: "Myname"}, payload2: {age: "Myage"}}

Comment: I don't believe the included objects have to have a relationship to the main body.